# Rotation and position:absolute (IE8 and lower)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, rotation

I have a problem with the rotation in Internet Explorer 8 and lower. 
I am able to rotare a parent div, but the child (positioned absolute) doesn't rotate with its parent. When I don't position the child absolute, it does the right rotation.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<style>
    .parent
    {
        background-color: #f00;
        position: absolute;
        top: 300px;
        left: 300px;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;

        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476, sizingMethod='auto expand'); //45deg
    }

    .child
    {
        background-color: #0f0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 150px;
        left: 150px;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;  
    }


</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="parent">
    This is the parent
    <div class="child">
        This is the child
    </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

When you view this code in IE8, then this is the result

[image]

I would like that the green div has the same rotation as the red div.

Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you rotating a div?  I've never found a use for it, I'm just curious on your motives.

Comment: I have to make a site that looks a bit like a prezi presentation :). http://prezi.com/

Comment: Oh, cool idea.  Well, good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround:

css:

```
.ie {
       display:none;
}
```

Comment: This works, but the position of the child to the parent is not the same as when there was no rotation.