# Why does IE8 and below rotate the container but not the content?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, rotation

I have a container with a background image and a span element with text. IE9, 10, and modern browsers are fine but ie7 and 8 does not rotate the content. It does, however, rotate to container.

I tried posting in jsfiddle but jsfiddle won't run in IE8 (at least when I tried it).

I've tried these:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

and

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=-0.00000000, M12=1.00000000, M21=-1.00000000, M22=-0.00000000,sizingMethod='auto expand')";
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=-0.00000000, M12=1.00000000, M21=-1.00000000, M22=-0.00000000,sizingMethod='auto expand');
```

Both work in IE9 and 10 but not IE8 and below.

Comment: The matrix filter should work in IE8. Do you get any error messages? Perhaps ActiveX Controls are disabled because of local security settings or an invalid doctype. Make sure IE7/8 are not running in quirks mode.

Comment: no errors, not running in quirks mode, and the doctype is the HTML5 doctype.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but some browsers just don't support certain things. http://caniuse.com/#compare=ie+7,ie+8,ie+9,ie+10

Comment: What's the `position:`ing of the container and the content? I've got a demo that [does what you're trying to do on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490216/) including if spans are added in IE8, where the container is `position: absolute;` and any content spans I add are default position. [See also this Q where child is pos:absolute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793415). Also, when you test are you testing in IE8 itself, or IE10 in IE8 mode? Because [IE10's default security settings deactivate "legacy filters"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340945/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching for the [ms-writing-mode property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?
This should have support for at least IE8.  I'm not quite sure about 7 and I don't have a browser to test it on.

Comment: Which property value are you suggesting would fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just bumped into this problem and I fixed it by setting `z-index` (to value 1 in my case) to the container. This made its child elements rotate along with the filter on the container.

Please note that my container was absolutely positioned, so I'd recommend `absolute` or `relative`.